# Unicode Decode Error while trying to use Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a simple program that reads a file and asks the user to input a word and then tells how many times that word is used.  I want to improve it so you don't have to type the exact directory each time.  I imported Tkinter and used the code fileName= filedialog.askfilename() so that a box pops up and lets me choose the file.  Every time I try to use it though I get the following error code...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AshleyStallings/Documents/School Work/Computer Programming/Side Projects/How many? (Python).py", line 24, in <module>
    for line in fileScan.read().split():   #reads a line of the file and stores
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The only time I don't seem to get this error code is when I try to open a .txt file.  But I'm wanting to open .docx files also.  Thanks for your help in advance :)

```
# Name: Ashley Stallings
# Program decription: Asks user to input a word to search for in a specified
# file and then tells how many times it's used.
from tkinter import filedialog

print ("Hello! Welcome to the 'How Many' program.")
fileName= filedialog.askopenfilename()  #Gets file name


cont = "Yes"

while cont == "Yes":
    word=input("Please enter the word you would like to scan for. ") #Asks for word
    capitalized= word.capitalize()  
    lowercase= word.lower()
    accumulator = 0

    print ("\n")
    print ("\n")        #making it pretty
    print ("Searching...")

    fileScan= open(fileName, 'r')  #Opens file

    for line in fileScan.read().split():   #reads a line of the file and stores
        line=line.rstrip("\n")
        if line == capitalized or line == lowercase:
            accumulator += 1
    fileScan.close

    print ("The word", word, "is in the file", accumulator, "times.")

    cont = input ('Type "Yes" to check for another word or \
"No" to quit. ')  #deciding next step
    cont = cont.capitalize()

    if cont != "No" and cont != "Yes":
        print ("Invalid input!")

print ("\n")
print ("Thanks for using How Many!")  #ending
```

P.S. Not sure if it matters, but I'm running OSx

Comment: As a side note, you almost certainly don't want `for line in fileScan.read().split():`—that will treat each word as a separate line. You probably just want `for line in fileScan:`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm splitting it at the words though so that it can compare each word to the word it's searching for.  And then add one each time the word is found.

Comment: Then the name and comments are misleading, because it doesn't read a line of the file, it reads the whole file, and splits it into words, not caring about the separate lines. And the `rstrip` is useless in that case, because you've already split out all the whitespace.

Comment: Another aside: `fileScan.close` is not going to close the file, that is just the reference to the `close` method (you forgot to call it by adding `()`). You might also want to look at using the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) like the following, which saves you from closing the file manually: `with open(fileName, 'r') as fileScan:`

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys.  This is one of my first time working with files in Python so I'm still trying to figure it all out :)

Comment: Also, for future reference: There's really nothing tkinter-related here; if you can strip your code down to the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem (which, here, is probably just `for line in open('foo.docx'): pass`), it will be easier for people to answer you. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for details.

Answer (score 3):

> The only time I don't seem to get this error code is when I try to open a .txt file. But I'm wanting to open .docx files also.

A `docx` file isn't just a text file; it's an [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file: a zipfile containing an XML document and any other supporting files. Trying to read it as a text file isn't going to work.

For example, the first 4 bytes of the file are going to be this:

```
b'PK\x03\x04`
```

You can't interpret that as UTF-8, ASCII, or anything else without getting a bunch of garbage. You're certainly not going to find your words in this.

---

You can do some processing on your own—use `zipfile` to access the `document.xml` inside the archive, then use an XML parser to get the text nodes, and then rejoin them so you can split them on whitespace. For example:

```
import itertools
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with zipfile.ZipFile('foo.docx') as z:
    document = z.open('word/document.xml')
    tree = ET.parse(document)

textnodes = tree.findall('.//{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t')
text = itertools.chain.from_iterable(node.text.split() for node in textnodes)
for word in text:
    # ...
```

Of course it would be better to actually parse the `xmlns` declarations and register the `w` namespace properly, so you can just use `'w:t'`, but if you have any idea what that means, you already know that, and if you don't, this isn't the place for a tutorial on XML namespaces and `ElementTree`.

---

So, how are you supposed to know that it's a zipfile full of stuff, and the actual text is in the file `word/document.xml`, and the actual text within that file is in the `.//w:t` nodes, and the namespace `w` maps to `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main`, and so on? Well, you could read all the relevant documentation and figure it out, using some sample files and a bit of exploration to guide you, if you already know enough about this stuff. But if you don't, there's a major learning curve ahead of you.

And even if you do know what you're doing, it would probably be a better idea to [search PyPI for a docx parser module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=docx&submit=search) and just use that.